# Jquery Ajax In codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use jQuery ajax in Codeigniter. In previous projects I already used jQuery ajax but this time I am getting problems. Below is my code

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"<?php echo base_url()?>register",
  data:{
    name:$("#f_name").val()
  },
  cache:false,
  success:function(result){
    $("#registration_result").html(result);                  
    alert("success");
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("fail");
  }
});
```

Here the problem is even I am not getting the Error message "Fail". Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Have you got any error in console? if so then plz share. use php tag or code in js isn't a good practice.

Comment: @crack : I am getting this error "MOCK POST: http://localhost/ClickMyStay/register 
Object {url: "http://localhost/ClickMyStay/register", isLocal: false, global: true, type: "POST", contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"…}"

Comment: Hey i found this in one of the js file.
$.extend({ajax: handleAjax});
I removed it and Its working Fine...!!

Comment: nice, but you didn't mention it. :)

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. What should i mention.?

Comment: $.extend({ajax: handleAjax});

Comment: Actually i came to know about that when u said to check in console....:-)  So then i tried it and it worked..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your register page url, maybe the page is not found, 
so ajax fall into error-function,

```
  error:function(){
    alert("<?php echo base_url()?>register");
    alert("fail");
  }
```

when your ajax running it will alert "url register", then please open that url, to check if the page is exist or not.

If the register-page is not exist,

- Make sure **register controller** is exist
- Check value of **"index_page" application/config/config.php**

  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

If the value is "index.php", change your ajax-url into

```
url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/register",
```